# Get constraint of uibutton programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have 4 buttons in Storyboard with BottomSpace and Horizontal Alignment constraints. Is there a way to access those constraints constants without linking them as outlets? I want to update those constants when the user press a button so the ideal case in pseudocode would be:

```
func buttonPressed(_ button: UIButton) {
      button.bottomSpaceConstraint.constant += 10
      button.horizontalAlignment.constant += 10
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Of course that you can access them, but there is a lot of trouble to figure what kind of constraints are those. i.e: `button.contraints` which is an array of `NSLayoutConstraint`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To expand on Stormsyder's answer, there is a much cleaner way to do the same thing using the `filter` method. See the following:

```
let bottomConstraint = button.superview!.constraints.filter({ $0.firstAttribute == .bottom && $0.firstItem == button }).first!
let horizontalAllignmentConstraint = button.superview!.constraints.filter({ $0.firstAttribute == .centerX && $0.firstItem == button }).first!
```

Note this will crash if those constraints don't exist so make sure they do or unwrap safely.

Comment: I haven't been able to try it out yet because although I have those coinstraints in IB they are not in button.constraints. Printing button.constraints only shows the heigh and width any idea why?

Comment: Ah okay, yes that is because the constraints for positioning technically belong to the superview. See my updated answer.

Comment: Is this answer still valid? I'm getting: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject?' and 'UIButton?'

Comment: @Oscar Seems odd, try `$0.firstItem == (button as? AnyObject)`

Comment: use this
`$0.firstItem === button`

Comment: I can maybe  use  `$0.identifier == "buttonBottom"`

Answer (score 3):

**Answer for swift 3:**

```
func buttonPressed(_ button: UIButton) {
    for constraint in button.superview!.constraints {
        if constraint.firstAttribute == .bottom {
            constraint.constant += 10
        }
    for constraint in button.constraints {
        if constraint.firstAttribute == .centerY {
            constraint.constant += 10
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jacob King you made an error in your answer, which is near from being correct, I'll update the correction in my answer

Comment: Oops, thanks. I just noticed another error in my answer, on the horizontal line, missed of the `first!` at the end. I'll suggest an edit.

Comment: No problem, I'll delete it from my post since the answer belongs to you (I couldn't comment on your post, I'm only 24 rep ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can get constraints :

```
func buttonPressed(_ button: UIButton) {
    let array = button?.superview?.constraints

    for constrains  in array! {
        print( constrains.constant)
    }

}
```